# Index out of range error when accessing embedded struct value

Tags: go

I get an out of range error when I run this code:

Go:

```
type Ping struct {
    Content []aContent
}

type aContent struct {
    Type        string
    Id          string
    Created_at  int64
}

var p Ping

func main() {

f := Ping{Content: []aContent{{Type: "Hello", Id: "asdf"}}}
fmt.Println(f)
fmt.Println(p.Content[0].Created_at) //what's wrong?
}
```

What's wrong? The code can be found here: http://play.golang.org/p/uZm5LaUuGW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable `p` of type `Ping` and its field/property `Content` is un-initialized, so when you access the content of the `Content` which is a `slice`, it throws you that error. Why? Because the value of an uninitialized `slice` is `nil`. i.e `p.Content == []`

Comment: +1. Youre initializing `f` but trying to print a value within `p` (which isnt initialized).